# Python: Using Regex to remove multiple occurrences of punctuation?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to remove reoccurring punctuation in a row.

E.g turn 'Hello...' into 'Hello.'

I've been reading some of the documentation on the matter, but am struggling to find a definitive method. (I personally find the docs on regex to a be a little overwhelming, and unclear at times).

I thought it may be something along the lines of:

```
re.sub('[!()-{};:,<>./?@#$%^&*_~]+', '', input)
```

But this doesn't work. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Although it is closed, I wrote such a code:
`re.sub(r'([!()\-{};:,<>./?@#$%\^&*_~])\1+', lambda x: x.group()[0], t)` (when I was writing it the question was not closed yet).

Comment: @Splitter, Thank you greatly for your response. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
import re
input='Hello...' 
re.sub(r'(\W)(?=\1)', '', input)
```

Output:

```
'Hello.'
```

Comment: The problem is that if an input is 'test  \n\n\n test', the result is 'test \n test'.